# GHCi cannot find modules of my program

Tags: haskell, emacs, cabal

I'm working on a project and I'm using Cabal for management. I've specified directory of source files, modules, all the stuff. All my files have the same names as their corresponding modules, case is preserved.

I can do:

```
$ cabal configure
$ cabal build
```

without problems.

However, imagine I have a module `Module` in file `Module.hs`, and file `File.hs` in the same directory. Now, when I'm trying to load `File.hs` from Emacs for testing, I get the following:

```
____Could not find module ‘Module’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘ghc-7.8.3’.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Full contents of `File.hs`:

```
module File where
import Module
```

How to make it find files of my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell GHCi where to find your source files.  For example, if your project directory is `./foo` and you have your source files in `./foo/src` you need to say (from your project directory):

```
:set -isrc
```

at the command prompt in GHCi.  You will then have access to private members in your sourc file loaded with `C-c C-l`.

You also need to make sure that you haven't `cabal install`ed your package, otherwise the package will be loaded, not the project source files.

Answer (score 8):

You can launch the REPL via Cabal like so:

# cabal repl

This is the same as running `ghci`, but will take into account any additional dependencies installed by cabal install your local or sandbox package repository.

Comment: Well, it loads just everything, not specific file. I have no access to non-public functions in module that I'm working on. I like to do `C-c C-l` and load current module it into GHCi, it is quite convenient. Maybe there is a way to save this workflow... Thank for your answer anyway.

Comment: After starting the repl, you can import an individual source file directly with `:load`. i.e. 

    `:load MyFile.hs`

This will then give you direct access to internal/private members

Comment: Also:

```# stack repl```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed it, and decided to write about my troubleshooting. This might help new people learning Haskell. Read on.

I was playing around with this example code.

http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputdirectory/getCurrentDirectory_f.html

Code:

```
import Directory 

main = aaa "/tmp/FOO"

aaa ddd = do createDirectory ddd
        setCurrentDirectory ddd
        d <- getCurrentDirectory
        print d
        writeFile "aaa" "HELLO"
        l <- getDirectoryContents d
        print l
```

I noticed that they are using this package.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.6.2/docs/System-Directory.html

So I installed it with this commands:

```
cabal update
cabal install directory
```

Compiling the example code with `ghc` failed with this error message.

```
    Could not find module `Directory'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
4 | import Directory
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I was stuck for a while until I changed the import line to this:

```
import System.Directory
```

After this change `ghc` could compile successfully.

**Conclussion**: are you sure you are importing properly?